# When am I allowed cross-thread access and when am I not?

Tags: c#, multithreading

It seems that C# throws exceptions for cross-threading operations sometimes. For example, you can try running this sample code in a Windows Forms program:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Thread setTextT = new Thread(TextSetter);
        setTextT.Start();
    }

    private void TextSetter()
    {
        //Thread.Sleep(4000);
        textBox1.Text = "Hello World";
    }
```

It doesn't throw any exceptions, everything seems to be working fine. Now, when you uncomment the Thread.Sleep line, it'll throw an exception for attempted cross-threading access.

Why is this the case?

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't blow up on you.  You should never do it, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because the cross thread check only happens after [the window's handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has been created, as the thing you are checking for is cross thread accessing of the window handle. When you don't have the sleep in there the code runs quickly enough before the control is displayed for the the first time (the handle gets created the first time the control is displayed).

The easyist way to know if you need to be careful of cross thread access of a UI control is just check [`InvokeRequired`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and if it is true you need to call [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (or `BeginInvoke` if you don't want to wait for it to complete) to get on the thread that created the control.

Comment: This is why you should start the thread in the Load event of the form, rather than from the constructor. That way, you'll get more consistent behaviour.

Comment: @Baldrick Good point. @Andrew The `Load` event occurs after the form has been loaded and displayed, that way you now know that you don't need to worry about the control being created in the middle of your method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Thread setTextT = new Thread(TextSetter);
        setTextT.Start();
    }

    private void TextSetter()
    {
        //Thread.Sleep(4000);
        //textBox1.Text = "Hello World";
        //You have to Invoke your action to the UI thread
        Invoke(new Action(()=>textBox1.Text = "Hello World"));
    }
```